# How to update data from device via REST to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have been working on a problem, where I want to update the value on Firebase Real-time Database.

I am unable to understand is there any way where I can validate my HTTPS request by my custom AUTH key? As I don't want the device to get the auth token from user authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass an `auth` parameter with the HTTP request: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#auth. If you have problems making this work, show the minimal code that allows us to reproduce that problem please.